# Chartjs - Remove the padding from the right side of the yAxes/xAxes?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I can't seem to find any way to remove the right side padding so the text aligns further to the right... I presume this is because the label is centered with the point, but for the first and last one I would them them to possibly moved "inwards".

I also assume this needs to be done on the xAxes, but I could be incorrect.

See example!

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. Do both of the images show the problem? Or does the 2nd image demonstrate what you want?

Comment: Second image demonstrates what I am looking for.

Comment: I haven't been able to find any options in the Chart JS docs for doing this. Unfortunately Chart JS renders to canvas, so we don't have much manual control over the chart. There might be a way to hack it, but it does not look like this feature exists by default.